# Python Addition and Subtraction with subsequent operators

Tags: python

Why does `1+-+1` equal to `0`?
If there is something mentioned in the documentation about this, could you link to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
1 + - + 1
```

Expands to

```
1 + ( - ( + 1)) == 1 + (- 1) == 1 - 1 == 0
```

Read more about evaluation order [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order).

Comment: "Python evaluates expressions from left to right". Thank you.